How to change month names ant design vue calendar component?
I use vue with ant design. i get simple example a-calendar. but i cannot change locale. i need change month and week names. here my code:
<a-calendar
      v-model:value="value"
      bordered
      class="shadow-lg rounded-lg bg-white px-4"
      :locale="calendarLocale"
      :monthNames="calendarLocale.monthNames"
    >
      <template #dateCellRender="{ current }">
        <ul class="events">
          <li v-for="item in getListData(current)" :key="item.content">
            <a-badge :status="item.type" :text="item.content" />
          </li>
        </ul>
      </template>
      <template #monthCellRender="{ current }">
        <div v-if="getMonthData(current)" class="notes-month">
          <section>{{ getMonthData(current) }}</section>
          <span>Backlog number</span>
        </div>
      </template>
    </a-calendar>
<script setup>
import locale from '@/utils/locale'
import { ref, computed } from 'vue'
const value = ref()
const calendarLocale = computed(() => locale)
}
</script>

it is my calendarLocale:
const locale = {
    lang: {
    locale: 'tm',
   //some other props
    monthNames: [
      'Ýanwar',
      'Fewral',
      'Mart',
      'Aprel',
      'Maý',
      'Iýun',
      'Iýul',
      'Awgust',
      'Sentýabr',
      'Oktýabr',
      'Noýabr',
      'Dekabr'
    ]
  }
}

export default locale

i dont know how to change. here dont change monthNames

Can you clarify what's your case? It already provides locales https://www.antdv.com/components/calendar#api , you may need to use the existing locale implementation instead of reinventing the wheel

There is no "tm" language code. Your list of month names would match the "tk" or Turkmen language though

I think 'tm' it is Turkmen, so you can import 'tk' locale from 'dayjs' to set your default locale globally:
import { dayjs } from 'dayjs'
import 'dayjs/locale/tk'

dayjs.locale('tk')

Here is all the changes for 'tk' locale:
https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs/blob/dev/src/locale/tk.js
This note about locale is avaiable in #API session at AntDesign docs.
https://www.antdv.com/components/calendar#api
